# How to enumerate default values of a structure in C++

Tags: c++, struct, enums

**Problem:**
I have a structure that represent RGB colors. I would like to define an enum to be able to directly assign the colors to a variable.

**1) Desired enum of struct:**
What I would like is to define an enum that directly maps a color name to its value, just like I would do with an integer parameter or a list of items.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

typedef struct _Color_3u8
{
    std::array<unsigned char,3> rgb;
} Color_3u8;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Color_3u8& dt)
{
    os << "R: " << (int)dt.rgb[0] << " | G: " << (int)dt.rgb[1] << " | B: " << (int)dt.rgb[2] << "\n";
    return os;
}

typedef enum _Default_color
{
    RED = (Color_3u8){255,0,0},
    GREEN = (Color_3u8){0,255,0},
    BLUE = (Color_3u8){0,0,255},
} Default_color;

int main()
{
    Color_3u8 my_color = Default_color::RED;
    std::cout << my_color;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the code above clearly doesn't work because enums are limited to integers.

**2) constant array + enum:**
One way to make it work is to use a constant array filled with the vaules and use the enum to index that array. It looks a lot clunkier since there are two separate definitions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

typedef struct _Color_3u8
{
    std::array<unsigned char,3> rgb;
} Color_3u8;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Color_3u8& dt)
{
    os << "R: " << (int)dt.rgb[0] << " | G: " << (int)dt.rgb[1] << " | B: " << (int)dt.rgb[2] << "\n";
    return os;
}

typedef enum _Default_color
{
    RED = 0,
    GREEN = 1,
    BLUE = 2,
    NUM_COLORS = 3,
} Default_color;


const std::array<Color_3u8,Default_color::NUM_COLORS> c_default_colors=
{
    (Color_3u8){255,0,0},
    (Color_3u8){0,255,0},
    (Color_3u8){0,0,255},
};

int main()
{
    Color_3u8 my_color = c_default_colors[Default_color::BLUE];
    std::cout << my_color;
    return 0;
}
```

`Output: "R: 0 | G: 0 | B: 255"`

**3) struct class:**
Another way I can think of is to move the constant array from code 2) inside the structure and add a method to initialize the structure to a default color. It would work and it would be very clean, but like the 2), it would be more effort to add a color than I feels is necessary... I feel there should be a way to make code 1) work in some form.

**4) Hack struct into integer**
In this case since my structure is three bytes, I can convert a color to its integer representation and use that for the enum. I would like to find a way that works with structures bigger than an int as well.

**Solution) namespace+constexpr**
constexpr is used to declare a compile time variable ofthe right type with the right constructor. namespace wraps around the definitions and scope them.

```cpp
struct Color_3u8
{
    std::array<unsigned char,3> rgb;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Color_3u8& dt)
{
    os << "R: " << (int)dt.rgb[0] << " | G: " << (int)dt.rgb[1] << " | B: " << (int)dt.rgb[2] << "\n";
    return os;
}

namespace Default_color
{
    constexpr Color_3u8 RED{255,0,0};
    constexpr Color_3u8 GREEN{0,255,0};
    constexpr Color_3u8 BLUE{0,0,255};
};

int main()
{
    Color_3u8 my_color = Default_color::RED;
    std::cout << my_color;
    return 0;
}
```

**Question**
Is there a way in C++ to make something similar to code 1)? I would like to map a name to a structure content with just one entry in one table, like the enum does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use inline constexpr variables and wrap them in a namespace.  That would look like

```
namespace Default_colors
{
    inline constexpr Color_3u8 RED{255,0,0};
    inline constexpr Color_3u8 GREEN{0,255,0};
    inline constexpr Color_3u8 BLUE{0,0,255};
}
```

and then you would use it like

```
Default_colors::RED
```

The reason to use inline variables here is so you can declare them in a header file and not have to worry about defining them in a single translation unit.

---

Also note that in C++, there is no reason to do

```
typedef struct _Color_3u8
{
    std::array<unsigned char,3> rgb;
} Color_3u8;
```

like you have to do in C.  In C++, you can just use

```
struct Color_3u8
{
    std::array<unsigned char,3> rgb;
};
```

Comment: This works, thanks! There is a typo `constexp` -> `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

What if I told you that you can store information about all the three colors in a single variable? Will you believe me? Well this is how, 
If you know about binary, if we OR something, it adds the '1' bit to a certain location (in binary). This means that we can assign a binary value to each color, and by OR-ing it, we can store the data about the color.

```cpp
#define BIT_SHIFT(x)    (1 << x)

enum Colors {
    Red = BIR_SHIFT(0),    // Which is gonna be 1.
    Green = BIR_SHIFT(1),    // Which is gonna be 2.
    Blue = BIR_SHIFT(2),    // Which is gonna be 4.
};
```

Now we can have a variable to store the colors,

```cpp
int colors = Colors::Red | Colors::Green;
```

Now when were gonna print, we just need to AND the color to check if its there.

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Color_3u8& dt)
{
    // Red color value.
    if(colors & Colors::Red)
        os << "R: 255 |";
    else 
        os << "R: 0 |"

    // Green color value.
    if(colors & Colors::Green)
        os << "G: 255 |";
    else 
        os << "G: 0 |"

    // Blue color value.
    if(colors & Colors::Blue)
        os << "B: 255\n";
    else 
        os << "B: 0\n"

    return os;
}
```

One downside of using this is that you cant store the individual color values (meaning its gonna be either 0 or 255, which I came to conclusion using the example). But on the plus size, you only need one variable to get it done.

Comment: I think this bithacking is more useful in microcontrollers with limited memory footprint, here I was looking for a way to do it 'properly'. Thanks anyway.